# How to fix React Native Android Error Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I run the command "npx react-native run-android" to install and debug the App on the Android device, I encountered this error but am clueless on where to start looking to debug this issue. From what it shows, it seems to be a missing android:value to one of the  in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Looking for advice on where to start looking into to debug. Thank you!

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless@value value=(org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader) from [:unimodules-react-native-adapter] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-88
> is also present at [:expo-modules-core] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-86 value=(expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:91 to override.

Gradle file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.gozouk">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@joetan7/goZouk"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="40.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="React Native Market"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <!-- Added for agora foreground -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.notification_channel_name"
        android:value="Sticky Title"
        />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.notification_channel_description"
        android:value="Sticky Description."
        />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/blue"
        />
    <service android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.ForegroundService"></service>
    <service android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.ForegroundServiceTask"></service>
    <!-- End of content to add -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.gozouk"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="fb820370405209413"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504370/manifest-merger-failed-after-adding-and-linking-react-native-device-info)?

Comment: It could be a different issue, i'm not sure. It seems like unimodules-react-native-adapter and expo-modules-core has the same RNHeadlessAppLoader

Comment: In the end, I found it is a package version mismatch.